# Plausible Anatomy for Humanoid Turtle Shoulders

Tags: humanoid, anatomy

There are many depictions of humanoid/simian creatures with turtle-like shells. There is one obvious issue with this setup: A turtle's shell is its ribcage, with the shoulders set inside. This clearly poses an issue for the usual humanoid shoulder structure, or in fact almost any other existing shoulder from outside of the turtles

**Given this issue, Is there any anatomically realistic structure that would allow a turtle's shell to coexist with humanoid shoulders?**

Comment: human shoulders are so unlike most other animals you may need to describe what exactly about turtle shoulders gives you a problem.

Comment: Some pictures would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have it made by extending the [vertebral processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertebra)

> The posterior part of a vertebra forms a vertebral arch, in eleven parts, consisting of two pedicles, two laminae, and seven processes.

If these extensions wrap around the torso, they act as a shell while leaving the human shoulder almost untouched.

The only problem being that the arms won't be retractable inside the shell, if the shell extends until the sternum.

Comment: Well, the shell doesn't *need* to extend all around. I'd think a back-only shell would be sufficient for protective purposes and giving the turtlish look.

Answer (score 1):

### Strength

What if this (bipedal) human carrying a heavy shield on its back would just be very strong..

**Tailbone**

It would come in handy if this human species did not completely degenerate the tail bone, keep it, make it short, broader, maybe connect it to the pelvis, or hips, or belly muscles, in some way. The construct would help support the shield. Humans *are* bipedal..

**Upper body**

A rigid, sturdy - suitably bent - spinal chord, firmly connected to the shield, a strong breast and ribs.. musculature, everywhere..

**Shoulders**

Shoulders could remain human, with a set of very thick and sturdy clavicle bones. Human shoulders are already shaped to facilitate carrying weight. A backpack is carried using shoulder belts. Instead of belts, introduce muscle.

btw you bring back memories !! I don't know if *looking cute* is considered *realistic* ? remember below hero's, also depicted quite *strong*.. notice the belt, that was cheated in ! Translated to anatomy: strong belly musculature.. and/or a functional tailbone.

[image]
[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles